# Using Dummy variable in Rstudio to find mean, median, and SD of Y

Tags: r

Using the already created dummy variables: nonsmoker, light smoker, moderate smoker, and heavy smoker, I need to find the mean, median and SD of birthweights(Y) for each dummy group. I am sure the code is simple, but it slipped my head and can't find the right answer.

Comment: Maybe look at `?aggregate`. You'll have to aggregate by each dummy column separately. Btw, best to be clear about your data set and the variable of interest, MASS::birthwt and bwt here, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(data.table)

cats <- c('non-smoker', 
          'heavy-smoker',
          'moderate-smoker', 
          'light-smoker')

df <- data.frame(bweight = 100 + 30*rnorm(100), 
                 status = sample(cats,100, replace = T) )


dt <- data.table(df)


dt2 <- dt[,.(mean = mean(bweight), 
  sd = sd(bweight), 
  median  =median(bweight)), 
   status]

dt2

        status      mean       sd    median
1:    heavy-smoker 108.02752 22.56118 113.35685
2:    light-smoker 100.86848 30.78375 104.00167
3:      non-smoker  95.92386 24.54260  97.62238
4: moderate-smoker 106.45183 29.73191 106.81698
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, you're right I should be using set.seed, i'll try to remember next time.